# Convert date to numeric in R

Tags: linear-programming

Task: Construct a forecast with linear or quadratic deterministic trend for future number of employees in US Retail trade.

Link to the data:
https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/USTRADE?fbclid=IwAR0-YU8nyc8iQCLOjd9DxRsU8G_GNEWEow_g2a6ob1cP0bu_xQSXO1FFPi8

Once data is downloaded. I use this code to load it.

```
Employees_data <- read.csv(file.choose(), header=TRUE, sep = ",")
```

Then I realize my date column is formatted as "factor", so I use this code:

```
Employees_data$DATE <- as.Date(Employees_data$DATE,"%Y-%m-%d")
```

Then I try to do a lm(), but realize I need 2 numeric values.

```
LinearModel <- lm(Employees_data$USTRADE~Employees_data$DATE)
```

So I convert date to numeric now using:

```
Employees_data$DATE <- as.numeric(Employees_data$DATE)
```

But what do I know, now I get negative numeric values for my date column.

```
data.frame':    968 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ DATE   : num  -11323 -11292 -11264 -11233 -11203 ...
 $ USTRADE: num  3108 3122 3140 3155 3152 ...
```

When I converted the date column to number in Excel I get these values:

```
Date    Employees
14.246   31.071     
14.277   31.211        
...
```

Where the numbers in Date column indicate the number of days. Having this I can do the regression in Excel using Employees as Y and Date as X

Getting a lovely result:

```
    Coefficients
Intercept   -48685,09628
Date    5,079443779
```

How can I do this in R? I'm trying to learn R.

any help is appreciated :)

Comment: This question contains a lot of narrative information that doesn't help people answer your question on how to convert a date to numeric in R.  Furthermore, getting people to give you the answer in R is likely not the best way for most people to learn a new programming language.

Comment: Sorry it's my first post. Here is the question:
why do i get negative values when i try to convert date to numeric value? 

using:

 'Employees_data$DATE <- as.numeric(Employees_data$DATE)'
i get:  -11323 -11292 ....
i expect 14.246  & 14.277.....